# How to un-merge all cells when writing a Pandas dateframe to Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I have a CSV file I am putting into a data frame and then writing the data to Excel. The CSV looks like:

```
ID, Number, Date, Code, Plan
```

And my current code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook


df=pd.read_csv("My File.csv")

book = load_workbook("My Workbook.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("'My Workbook.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title,ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet 1", merge_cells=False)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

What I'm running into is when I open the Excel worksheet I'll have an ID I would expect four rows for, but in Excel cells A2 & A3 are merged, then A4 and A5 are merged and this is for the same ID.

Here is the message I get when I go to open the Excel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
-<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">     
   <logFileName>error046640_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'Y:\Client Files\Weis\Automated Reports\Payroll Report\Weis Chart.xlsx'</summary>
-<removedRecords summary="Following is a list of removed records:">  
    <removedRecord>Removed Records: Merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</removedRecord>
   <removedRecord>Removed Records: Merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part</removedRecord>
  </removedRecords>
 </recoveryLog>
```

Comment: I've personally never used `writer.close` (I think there's a type-o in your code there). What happens if you remove that? Could you also post a small sample of your data frame?

Comment: The other thing i would check is if "My Workbook" already has merged cells inside of it? is that true? You could also check by changing `to_excel` to a new path and seeing if there are still merged cells.

Comment: That's what it was. The workbook already had merged cells.

Comment: I figured, I'm glad I could help. What I would personally do is save it to a new file path and that might solve your issue.